# Finding The Number Of Solutions To $e^x -2 = \cos x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, exponential-function

Hello everyone how many solution the equation $e^x -2 = \cos x$ have?

I tried to convert it to a function $y = e^x - \cos x -2$ and Find extreme points by:

$y' = e^x + \sin x$ but I don't know how to solve this equation.

Comment: You can find one solution through a simple application of the Intermediate Value Theorem. To argue there is exactly one solution, suppose there are two and apply Rolle’s theorem to obtain a contradiction

Answer (score 3):

Solutions can only be found where

$$-1\le e^x-2\le1,$$  i.e. $x\in[0,\log 3].$ In this range, $e^x-2$ is increasing and $\cos x$ decreasing, and there can only be one solution, which does exist, as

$$e^0-2<\cos0\land e^1-2>\cos1^*.$$

---

$^*$By Taylor,

$$e-2>\frac12+\frac1{3!}=0.6666666\cdots$$ and
$$\cos1<1-\frac12+\frac1{4!}=0.5416666\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Just a visive approach with Desmos plotting two elementary functions $f(x)=\cos x$ and $g(x)=e^x-2$ (it is the $e^x$ shifted down of $-2$) and you can seen one only solution.

[image]